# MS Access: Order of Events in event ApplyFilter (ADP Project)

Tags: ms-access, adp

I'm having problems with the execution of ServerFilterByForm in Access 2003
When I apply the entered filter it returns the requested data but after it appear on screen (Form) it disappears. Don't know why this is happening

Does anyone had the same problem? How can it be solved?
Here is part of the code"

```
Private Sub Form_ApplyFilter(Cancel As Integer, ApplyType As Integer)
    Dim stSql As String

    If Len(ServerFilter) > 0 Then
        stSql = "SELECT * FROM v_InitialReviewQuery " & _
                " WHERE " + ServerFilter & _
                " ORDER BY acctnumber"

    Else
        stSql = "SELECT top 1 * FROM v_InitialReviewQuery ORDER BY acctnumber"
    End If


    Me.RecordSource = stSql
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changeing this line

```
" WHERE " + ServerFilter & _
```

To

```
" WHERE " & ServerFilter & _
```

Also what is the value of ServerFilter?

Comment: I doubt that would solve the problem, but it is important to use the correct concatenation operator. & is for normal concatenation (ignores Nulls) and + is to propagate Nulls. Null & "String" = "String", while Null + "String" = Null.

Comment: I did the change and got the same results.
The Value of my server filter dependes on what the user use for filter. Let say that is using Contains part of string "Her" on field sFirstName the value of ServerFilter is sFirstName Like '%Her%'.

Now when debugging I can see that the requested values are in Access. But after refreshing the page all info is gone from screen. I need to filter again with same values to get the info on screen.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar .adp.

The method I use to set the queue is a view on a form (I use it as a subform that has various process queues) that provides the critera for the serverfilter. This would replace your "select top 1 *" and me.recordsource. The form is imbedded as a sub form on a main form that I provide information about various queues. Number in line, next to be worked, next SLA expiration... I use this to open the initial form:

```
Dim stDocName As String
Dim stLinkCriteria As String
Dim Next_TD_ID As String

Forms![Launch_Control]![queue_subfrom].Form.Refresh
Next_ID = Forms![Launch_Control]![queue_subfrom].Form.[nxt_id]

stLinkCriteria = "nxt_ID = " & Next_ID
stDocName = "Work_form"
DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , stLinkCriteria
```

Then on the work_form I use 2 buttons

One for the next work_item in the que:

```
private sub next_button_click()
    dim nxt_id as string
    nxt_id = Forms![Launch_Control]![queue_subfrom].Form![nxt_id]
    Me.ServerFilter = "identifier_in_view = " & Nxt_id
    Me.Refresh
end sub
```

The other to call the filterby from command.

```
Private Sub button_click(button As String)

    Forms![your_form].Reviewer.SetFocus
    Me.ServerFilter = ""
    Me.Refresh
    Me.ServerFilterByForm = True
    Me.Refresh
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdServerFilterByForm
end Sub
```

FYI my subform refrence may not be exacly correct.

Hope this helps.